# How do I connect an HTML input to a python function?

Tags: python, html

I was writing a function in python that you input a number and then outputs other thing. I have the script's idea in my head but I don't know how to link the input that I made in the HTML file and then show the result in form of text, so...

How do I do it? Am I mad with that idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? Anyway, a simple tutorial in flask or django will solve your problem. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to add a comment without 50 rep. However I'll post it here to hopefully save you time.
The answer is, it depends. Are you using an IDE like Django or Flask?

Comment: Django and Flask are frameworks but yeah, I agree. You need something like Flask or Django to connect them. Or you can use cgi which is not fun.